# Retrieving the headers of a file (resource) using urllib in Python 3

Tags: python, http, python-3.x

In Python 3x, how can I get the headers such as content length before downloading a file? This

```
import urllib.request

aaa, bbb = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name)
bbb['Content-Length']
# or

ccc, ddd = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)
ddd['Content-Length']
```

seems like it's first downloading the whole file and then returns its headers. I think so because it takes plenty of time and returns the name either of the temp file (the 2nd case) or real one (the 1st case).

Or am I wrong?

What I want is to retrieve Content-Lenght first and then, depending on some condition, download and save or not do anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP has a special method named [HEAD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) that tells the server to send only the headers (including `Content-Length`, if any) and stop right before the sending the actual content.

But to tell `urllib` to use the HEAD method, you should switch to the newer [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) function:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
resp = urlopen(Request('http://httpbin.org/html', method='HEAD'))
headers = resp.info()
print(headers['Content-Length'])
```

To be precise, the HTTP specification doesn’t require `Content-Length` in a response to a HEAD request (or at all), but most servers, especially those that serve files, will include it.

Comment: will I have to do a request to the server twice then?

Comment: @jawanam Yes (if you decide to go ahead and download the file).